# Magento2 - remove tax / price-details from widget

Tags: magento2, tax

How can I get the price for a product WITHOUT any TAX / Shipping Details?

Currently it is `$block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type);` and gives out **price + price-details (tax etc)**.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: In the Admin Configuration first need to set on Price will display W/O Tax

Comment: What? I did try to set "exclude tax" in display price but then it just changed the text to "excl. 0% MwST" but I dont want to see that at all.